# Set a property inside a maven profile conditionally, depending on another profile

Tags: maven, properties, maven-profiles

Is there a way so that, **inside a maven profile**, I could **set a property to one value or another, *depending on whether another profile is also active*** ?

Example: for the sample below,

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <myProp>value-dev</myProp>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <myProp>value-prod</myProp>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <myProp>value-test</myProp>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

- if ONLY DEV is active, then I need ***myProp = value-dev***
- if DEV and TEST are active, then I need ***myProp = value-test***

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer, but just my humble advice: 1. It is in most cases not a good idea to build different artifacts for testing and production (there are exceptions of course, but these need to be carefully analysed). 2. Your logic seems to be too difficult: You seem to want different outcomes whether `dev` is active, `test` is active or both are active. I doubt that this is technically possible, but even if it were, it indicates that you are probably going the wrong way.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve?